# call another api controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When I call user controller (api/user), I am able to pass user credentials, however the application crashes with null exception error (**Value cannot be null**) in the values controller:

```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
   private cdwEntities db = new cdwEntities();

   public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
   {
       var data = db.database.AsQueryable();

       if (query.name != null)
       {
           data = data.Where(c => c.Name == query.name);
       }

       if (query.price != null)
       {
           data = data.Where(c => c.Price == query.price);
       }


       if (!data.Any())
       {
           var message = string.Format("error");
           return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
       }

       ***return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);***
   }

}
```

I believe this error is because valuescontroller method cannot pass null values as it always pass parameters(i.e. api/values/name=tom), hence when I call user controller, it throws null error because the system has not passed any parameters into the Valuescontroller from user controller.

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("user"))
        {
            var result = new itemController();
            return result.Get(query);
        }

        var message = string.Format("No data was found");
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
    }
```

}

Is their some built-in function i could use to solve this issue or any framework/library i should look into?
Many thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, extract that common code into a reusable separate function.

Comment: I agree with @SLaks . You should use a common service class which has that logic in..

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to clarify, are you suggesting I should carry out this task in values controller. I have two API controllers and I would like to be able to direct specific users to those api controllers.  Could any one please provide any guide/framework, in how do I go about doing this task.

Comment: Hmmm too bad, I have a GetMethod which should be moved to other controller. But I wanted to keep backward compatibility by `GetMethod() {return _otherController.GetMethod();}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not call one API endpoint method from other API endpoint. Instead you need to have proper segregation of code between API, Business Logic Layer and Data Access Layer. I would do it in following way -

API -

```
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        [Authorize]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] Query query)
        {
            BusinessLayer layer = new BusinessLayer();
            if (User.IsInRole("user"))
            {
                var result = layer.GetData(query);
                // use result here and return HttpResponseMessage
                var message = string.Format("No data was found");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your business logic layer -

```
   public ResultModel Get(Query query)
   {
       // Process your model Query here... and then return some meaningful result here...
       // Also call Data Access Layer Methods from here, instead of making direct database
       // (entity framework) calls...
   }
```

For better flexible and loosely coupled systems, you need to have [Dependency Injection (probably using Unity, but there are many other options like Autofac, Ninject etc.)](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/jumpstart-19-setting-up-dependency-injection-for-asp-net-web-api/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback and help. is this similar to using a repository in business logic layer. Please excuse my knowledge as new and still learning features of web api.

Comment: yes, you are right. It is repository pattern, I am suggesting you.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out that you should not often (ever?) call one view controller endpoint from another, but in the case that you need/want to, you need to be sure the target has been initialized properly. This is done using [ControllerBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbuilder%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

So instead of:

```
var result = new itemController();
return result.Get(query); // this will blow up!
```

You would do:

```
IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
itemController c = (itemController) factory.CreateController(
    ControllerContext.RequestContext, "item");
return c.Get(query);
```

This will ensure that the target view controller has been initialized with all necessary context.